# Look through a list to find unwanted combination

Tags: python, list

I am still quite new to python so bear with me.
I have a list of users, along with the roles that they are holding on to:

```
Role = [('Amy', 'Administrator'), 
        ('Brandon', 'Editor'), 
        ('Brandon', 'User'),
        ('Eric', 'User'), 
        ('Brandon', 'Administrator'), 
        ('Eric', 'Administrator')]
```

I also have another list of combinations that a user should not have:

```
Unwanted = [('Administrator', 'Editor'), 
            ('Administrator', 'User'), 
            ('Editor', 'User')]
```

The code should identify the unwanted combination that a user have

```
["Brandon:('Administrator', 'Editor')", "Brandon:('Administrator', 'User')", "Brandon:('Editor', 'User')", "Eric:('Administrator', 'User')"]
```

The code that I have tried:

```
Role.sort()
 
res = [list(i) for j, i in groupby(Role,
              lambda a: a[0])]

res.sort()

temp = []
results =[]

for x in res:
    for y in x:
        temp.append(y[1])
        name = y[0]
        for z in Unwanted:
                if z[0] and z[1] in temp:
                    results.append(y[0] + ":" + str(z))
                    break
        temp.clear()
print(results)

["Brandon:('Administrator', 'Editor')", "Brandon:('Administrator', 'User')", "Eric:('Administrator', 'User')"]
```

Which part am I missing that is causing this value to be omitted:
`"Brandon:('Editor', 'User')"`

Comment: This expression `if z[0] and z[1] in temp:` is not doing what you think is doing, the right way is `if z[0] in temp and z[1] in temp:`

Comment: I recommend giving your variables names relating to what they contain. It's hard to debug whether your y[0] in the x of the res is the name or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = defaultdict(list)
roles = [('Amy', 'Administrator'), 
        ('Brandon', 'Editor'), 
        ('Brandon', 'User'),
        ('Eric', 'User'), 
        ('Brandon', 'Administrator'), 
        ('Eric', 'Administrator')]

unwanted_lst = [('Administrator', 'Editor'), 
            ('Administrator', 'User'), 
            ('Editor', 'User')]
for role in roles:
    data[role[0]].append(role[1])
for user,roles in data.items():
    for unwanted in unwanted_lst:
        if unwanted[0] in roles and unwanted[1] in roles:
            print(f'{user} has unwanted roles {unwanted}')
```

output

```
Brandon has unwanted roles ('Administrator', 'Editor')
Brandon has unwanted roles ('Administrator', 'User')
Brandon has unwanted roles ('Editor', 'User')
Eric has unwanted roles ('Administrator', 'User')
```

Answer (score 0):

`if z[0] and z[1] in temp:` translates to `if z[0] == True and z[1] in temp`

For that reason, your code currently just prints everyone with user or editor in the second slot

Another issue is that `temp.clear()` is indented too far, so it clears the list after each addition.

```py
from itertools import groupby

Role = [('Amy', 'Administrator'), 
        ('Brandon', 'Editor'), 
        ('Brandon', 'User'),
        ('Eric', 'User'), 
        ('Brandon', 'Administrator'), 
        ('Eric', 'Administrator'),
        ('John', 'User')]


Unwanted = [('Administrator', 'Editor'), 
            ('Administrator', 'User'), 
            ('Editor', 'User')]

Role.sort()
 
list_of_list_of_user_roles = [
    list(i) 
    for _, i in groupby(
        Role, lambda a: a[0]
    )
]

list_of_list_of_user_roles.sort()

user_roles = []
results =[]

for list_of_user_roles in list_of_list_of_user_roles:
    for user, role in list_of_user_roles:
        user_roles.append(role)
        for unwanted_role_1, unwanted_role_2 in Unwanted:
                if unwanted_role_1 in user_roles and unwanted_role_2 in user_roles:
                    results.append(user + ":" + unwanted_role_1 + "," + unwanted_role_2)
                    break
    user_roles.clear()
print(results)
```